# How can I adjust my VCard code so that Android users can download straight to their contacts?

Tags: android, ios, github, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create digital business cards for my work. I have coded a VCF in Github so that when people go to the Github webpage they can download the VCard. It immediately opens as a new contact on iOS, but it doesn't work on Android. Is there a way to have a new contact open up upon downloading when using an Android?

Thank you!

Code:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Last;First;;;
FN: First  Last
ORG:Company;
TITLE:Position
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:name@company.com
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE:+1 800 000 0000
item1.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;Address
item1.X-ABADR:sg
item2.URL;type=pref:company.com
item2.X-ABLabel:_$!<HomePage>!$_
END:VCARD
```